# ¿Por qué me aparecen tareas pendientes?

Tags: soporte, barra-superior, colas-de-revisión

Hoy mismo he llegado a los 2000 puntos de reputación y se han activado las `herramientas de moderación`.

Me imagino que está relacionado pero ahora mismo y des de hace *horas* este es el aspecto que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podéis ver me aparecen 3 tareas pendientes (según el momento 4 o 5) pero no veo tarea alguna pendiente.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe?

Me pone nervioso @.@

---

Edit: Sigue igual, el número va cambiando pero siempre me aparece el numerito.

Comment: A mi también me ocurre eso. Imagino que es algún mecanismo de caché o similar ya que las colas de revisión se limpian rápidamente en el sitio.

Comment: Ídem, y siempre pensé que eran las publicaciones pendientes de revisión a las que no tengo acceso, por ejemplo porque ya emití directamente un voto de cierre, porque antes omití esa revisión, o porque es una edición mía pendiente de revisión (pero no sé si realmente es por esto)

Comment: Creo que esta es una pregunta para @konamiman :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El contador que aparece en la barra de navegación hace referencia a *todas las tareas de revisión pendientes en el sistema*. Los contadores que ves para cada tipo de tarea, en cambio, se refieren únicamente a *las tareas que tú puedes revisar*. No puedes revisar, por ejemplo, las tareas que ya has revisado anteriormente, las que se refieren a tus propias publicaciones, o aquellas relacionadas con un reporte que tú mismo has enviado.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la aclaración! Me ponía un poco nervioso ver siempre ese numerito y ahora cómo mínimo sé para qué es.

Comment: A mí me pasó lo mismo en su momento, pero no tenía el lujo de poder mirar en las fuentes :-)

Comment: Aunque eso sea lo que el fuente expresa, en mi opinión es un BUG ya que ningún sentido tiene, para mi, que me muestre que hay X tareas pendientes si solo hay Y tareas en las que yo puedo colaborar.

Comment: Me ocurrió lo mismo y creo que es un bug. Se debería filtrar según los niveles de acceso y mostrarte las tareas pendientes para ti, no tiene sentido que muestra tareas pendientes que no puedo realizar. Tarea pendiente para los programadores del sitio :)