# ¿Por qué el botoncillo naranja de revisiones no conduce directamente a las sugerencias de edición cuando se superan los 2000 puntos?

Tags: soporte, barra-superior, colas-de-revisión

Me fijé hace poco que el botón naranja al lado de `revisar` dirigía directamente a la [cola de ediciones sugeridas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits).

Esto ocurre así en otros sitios donde puedo revisar, por ejemplo en Ask Ubuntu me lleva a [Review Suggested Edits](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, hoy me dirige a la página genérica de [Revisar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nótese que esto me ocurre desde que llegué a los 2000 puntos y obtuve el privilegio de [acceso a herramientas de moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Esto es, desde hoy mismo. No puedo comparar el caso con otros sitios Beta, pues solo en otro más tengo más de 2000 puntos de reputación pero aún no se dio el caso de ver revisiones pendientes.

¿Es este el comportamiento deseado? Creo que lo de ir directamente a una cola de revisión era práctico porque reducía el número de clicks a la hora de acceder a una cola.

---

Confirmado: eliminé una publicación para volver al nivel <2000 y entonces el enlace volvió a apuntar a la cola de ediciones sugeridas.

Comment: fui a testear lo que comenta pero no habian revisiones asi que no pude, **como dicen en Youtube like si te paso lo mismo** son bromas. Saludos

Comment: P.D: pero confio en lo que usted comenta. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel yo eliminé una publicación para volver a <2000 pero me encuentro ahora con el mismo problema... [Acabo de proponer una revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/41378) para que alguien pueda probarlo :) Y observo que sí, sucede esto.

Comment: Aun asi deje una cosa en el chat, te resumo creo que han cambiado los permisos pera ver las lista, me refiero a la puntuacion que tienes que tener para ver alguna, pero no creo que esto afecte a lo que comentas.Saludos

Comment: falsa alarma fue fallo mio es que entre en la lista del meta y solo tenia tres, claro al estar en meta lo primero que intente tras leer su pregunta fue entrar en las lista, jaja, por eso no vi solo tres y no me aparecio tampoco ninguna publicacion en espera para revisar o algo asi,(en el fondo me sorprendio) no haber ningua pendiente, pero no me percate de eso en ese momento ahora entre por cosas del destino en las del SOes y me percate que todo sigue igual y me di cuenta del fallo que le comente.Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Es el comportamiento esperado

A partir del momento en que se te otorga el privilegio de [Acceso A Herramientas De Moderación (10K, o 2K en beta)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), se muestra el número total de revisiones pendientes, y el enlace dirige a [las colas de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review).

---

> **Un poco de historia**
>
> En el 2013 se solicitó en
>   [Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191638/304899) que se agregaran el
>   resto de las revisiones pendientes como forma de incentivar la
>   participación de revisores. Como resultado, se muestra desde el 2014
>   el número de revisiones pendientes para moderadores adiamantados y
>   usuarios con el privilegio de moderación.
>
> [image: The answer was review all along]
>
> Tiene una excepción: para evitar que el número sea astronómico, en
>   Stack Overflow se omite la cola de Votos de cierre.

Comment: ¡Fantástico! Muchas gracias por la investigación. No sabía de este hecho.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, considero más práctico el comportamiento de <2000 rep, pues te lleva directamente a una cola. Quizás lo más práctico es que el algoritmo determinara qué cola necesita más atención en cada momento y te dirigiera a ella automáticamente.

Comment: @fedorqui en muchas oportunidades se pidió en MSE que muestre el número de pendientes que pueden ser revisadas por el usuario (versus el total del sitio), y esto jamás se implementó. Asumo que personalizar esa función de la barra requiere de recursos que se evaluó no destinar. Por lo que creo que te sería más efectivo buscar esa funcionalidad en un userscript.

Comment: Sí, de hecho la duda en [¿Por qué me aparecen tareas pendientes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/837/83) es muy común y lía bastante. Entiendo que mantener un contador a tiempo real es costoso y, por tanto, toda mejora en esos números tiene poco recorrido actualmente.

Comment: @fedorqui exacto.. son de los típicos temas que decimos "muy bueno, pero no lo van a hacer jamás" ;-) ... Aunque obviamente podrías probar publicarlo, nunca se sabe