# La cola de revisión de ediciones sugeridas de meta requiere atención

Tags: soporte, meta, colas-de-revisión

La cola de revisión de ediciones sugeridas de meta requiere atención. Muestra un punto rojo.

En mi caso no me muestra las ediciones pendientes lo cual es normal que ocurra ya sea porque yo sugerí la edición o porque ya la "voté".

Recuerden que la moderación del sitio, incluyendo meta, la hacemos los miembros de la comunidad que hemos obtenido los privilegios para ello.

Relacionado

- [¿Por qué me aparecen tareas pendientes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/837/65)

Comment: Hola Rubén, las colas de revisión de Meta aparecen vacías, y no he entrado a esta sección desde hace un buen tiempo, además de que a mí no me aparece ningún punto rojo. no hay ningún elemento que requiera atención

Comment: @Phi Gracias. Ya no veo el punto rojo. Publiqué una respuesta con mas detalles.

Answer (score 1):

A los que pasaron a la cola de revisión de Meta, muchas gracias, ya no aparece el punto rojo.

Por cierto, mis ediciones sugeridas la semana pasada de [resumen y wiki](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/suspensiones-chat/info) de la etiqueta [suspensiones-chat](/questions/tagged/suspensiones-chat) han sido aprobadas.